# NTAccount.Translate Method fails with error Some or all identity references could not be translated

Tags: c#, .net, translate, user-accounts

```
PipeAccessRule par = new PipeAccessRule("Everyone", PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
```

This code fails with error:

> Some or all identity references could not be translated.

I guess this is because I'm using "Everyone" while launch my app on non-English local. On English system everything is OK.

How to avoid this? Is there some enum describes general user groups?

Stack trace:

```
at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)    
at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType)    
at System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity.ModifyAccess(AccessControlModification modification, AccessRule rule, Boolean& modified)    
at System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule(AccessRule rule)    
at System.IO.Pipes.PipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(PipeAccessRule rule)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved by using second constructor of PipeAccessRule and SecurityIdentifier instead of string:

```
System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sid = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null);
PipeAccessRule par = new PipeAccessRule(sid, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
```

Comment: thats nice, but if you want to add the permission for a specific user or group ? what then ? how can you get the sid ?

Comment: In my case I need onlu build-in group. In case if it's not I guess it's enough to use simply string, as it was in my original question.

Comment: And actually my problem was that same peace of code was running on different culture. If the culture is same, I guess it's OK to use "hardcoded" names.

Comment: +1 but just in case others find this `WellKnownSidType.WorldSid` more closely matches original intent of using `"Everyone"`

Answer (score 3):

For some reasons, BuiltinUsersSid doesn't seem to work properly in my case (remote servers can access to the pipe but local accesses to the pipe fail !)

Here is the code I used to give access to almost everything and now pipe can be accessed locally or remotely :

Please note that DomainSid parameter is in some cases populated with current user domain

```
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
[...]

            PipeSecurity lPipeSecurity = new PipeSecurity();
            try
            {
                PipeAccessRule lPar1 = new PipeAccessRule(@"NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK", PipeAccessRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
                lPipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(lPar1);
            }
            catch (Exception E1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(PrinterBase.DumpTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, true) + ": Exception when trying to give pipe rights to AUTORITY NT NETWORK"+E1.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier lSid = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null);
                PipeAccessRule lPar2 = new PipeAccessRule(lSid, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);

                lPipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(lPar2);
            }
            catch (Exception E2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(PrinterBase.DumpTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, true) + ": Exception when trying to give pipe rights to BuiltInSid "+E2.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                PipeAccessRule lPar3 = new PipeAccessRule(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Environment.UserDomainName, Environment.UserName), PipeAccessRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
                lPipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(lPar3);
            }
            catch (Exception E3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(PrinterBase.DumpTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, true) + ": Exception when trying to give pipe rights to current user "+E3.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier lSidWorld = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
                PipeAccessRule lPar4 = new PipeAccessRule(lSidWorld, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
                lPipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(lPar4);
            }
            catch (Exception E4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(PrinterBase.DumpTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, true) + ": Exception when trying to give rights to World "+E4.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier lSidLocal = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.LocalSid, null);
                PipeAccessRule lPar5 = new PipeAccessRule(lSidLocal, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
                lPipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(lPar5);
            }
            catch (Exception E5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(PrinterBase.DumpTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, true) + ": Exception when trying to give rights to Local "+E5.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                PipeAccessRule lPar6 = new PipeAccessRule(@"geneos", PipeAccessRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
                lPipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(lPar6);
            }
            catch (Exception E6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(PrinterBase.DumpTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, true) + ": Exception when trying to give pipe rights to geneos" + E6.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                WindowsIdentity lCurrentId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier lSidLocal = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.AccountAdministratorSid, lCurrentId.User.AccountDomainSid);
                PipeAccessRule lPar5 = new PipeAccessRule(lSidLocal, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
                lPipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(lPar5);
            }
            catch (Exception E7)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(PrinterBase.DumpTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, true) + ": Exception when trying to give rights to administrators " + E7.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier lSidLocal = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);
                PipeAccessRule lPar8 = new PipeAccessRule(lSidLocal, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
                lPipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(lPar8);
            }
            catch (Exception E8)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(PrinterBase.DumpTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, true) + ": Exception when trying to give rights to authenticated users " + E8.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                WindowsIdentity lCurrentId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier lSidLocal = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, lCurrentId.User.AccountDomainSid);
                PipeAccessRule lPar9 = new PipeAccessRule(lSidLocal, PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
                lPipeSecurity.AddAccessRule(lPar9);
            }
            catch (Exception E9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(PrinterBase.DumpTimestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, true) + ": Exception when trying to give rights to authenticated users on current user domain " + E9.Message);
            }


            lPipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(
                lNamedPipe, 
                PipeDirection.InOut, 
                NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, 
                PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, 
                PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 
                0, 
                0, 
                lPipeSecurity);
```